# How to clean dictionary by deleting old elements from it

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, dictionary

Given is `Dictionary<T, U>` in asp.net application. Application is running for a long time and new elements will be continuously added to the dictionary. My goal is to keep so many elements in Dictionary as possible, without "memory overflow" or other side effects. How should I clean the collection to give some memory free for new elements, by deleting old ones? How to check how many old elements and when should elements be deleted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using a managed language you are limited in the way how you can manage your memory and the practices of manual memory freeing or forcing garbage collector do it are all deemed as suboptimal.

So, there is no direct way to say how many elements your generic dictionary is allowed to keep and how much memory you still can claim. In the same time deleting some old values from the dictionary will not automatically lead to immediate increase of available memory.

This said, you can keep monitoring the memory currently allocated to your application using [GC.GetTotalMemory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.gettotalmemory.aspx) (as long as your object are fully manageable, e.g. contain no unmanaged code or data blocks) and compare it to the total system memory available to application.

Or, if you know the size of the objects you put into your `Dictionary<>`, you might be interested in using [MemoryFailPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.memoryfailpoint.aspx) class that will tell you if you can create a new object of the given size or not, so you won't bump into the `OutOfMemory` exception and have time to free some resources.

Finally, if you are using the dictionary as a cache, there are some built-in cache providers in ASP.NET, read [from here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178597%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). The cache will automatically drop objects that are obsolete or old in case of memory pressure.

Answer (score 5):

Have you checked out `Application.Cache` ?
Sounds to me like it's just what you need...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178597(v=vs.100).aspx

Quote:

> The advantage of using the application cache is that ASP.NET manages the cache and removes items when they expire or become invalidated, or when memory runs low.

Comment: If you want to use a separate LRU cache, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.aspx is similar to the ASP.NET Cache and available in .NET 4+

Answer (score 3):

This is not a simple task. It sounds as if you are using the dictionary as cache in which case you should look into [standard caching for asp.net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsbfdd8c%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

That said you could choose different strategies. You could choose to set an upper bound on the number of elements you want in the dictionary. This is can be done by having a linked list with elements and letting the dictionary store the `LinkedListElement<U>`. When ever you retrieve something from the dictionary, you move the `LinkedListElement<U>` to the front of the linked list. This way you always have the newest elements on top of the list. When you insert elements, you add them to both the linked list and the dictionary, and test if the dictionary size limit is met. If it is, you remove elements from the bottom of the linked list and the dictionary.

Remember locking!